# Selecting Values From Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two seperate tables. In the first table, there are a bunch of ad groups which have an id. In the second table are a bunch of ads which have a column which contains the ad_group id for each ad. The ad_group_id is merely the id for the ad group from the ad group table. Therefore, I'm trying to select all ads which have an ad_group_id of 103, 104,105,107,117117,and 120.

So I tried the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ad_group_id LIKE '%103%' OR ad_group_id LIKE '%104%'
OR ad_group_id LIKE '%105%' OR ad_group_id LIKE '%107%' OR ad_group_id LIKE '%117%' OR ad_group_id LIKE '%118%' OR ad_group_id LIKE '%120%';
```

So did the previous query work? YES

Was my query efficient? NO!

I am wondering how I can run the previous MySQL query in a more efficient manner.

EDIT:

```
AD GROUP - table 1
id    name
100   Tony
100   David
103   James
104   Ann
105   Jon
150   Sara

AD - table 2
keyword   ad_group_id
that        103
one         100
is          105
special     104
no          100
please      103
```

So I should end up with:

```
that        103
is          105
special     104
please      103
```

Hope that makes sense.

EDIT 2:

The following code gives the same result and is shorter, but I can't imagine doing this when there is more values I need to select.

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ad_group_id IN (103,104,105,107,117,118,120);
```

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Can you please add some examples of the data in these tables and the result you are looking for?

Comment: Why `LIKE`? Why not `=`?

Comment: I'm new to SQL and for some reason, I always use LIKE unless I have a specific value I need.

Comment: Why would you think that you'd be able to pull data for many IDs without in same way specifying the list you're interested in?  SQL isn't good at discerning intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you store ad_group_id like id1,id2,id3 and so on.
If yes this relation is many-to-many and more effectively to create additional table with 
2 columns ad_id,ad_group_id. But it depends on amount of your data.